# Firebase Javascript multiple delete on single click

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing on a web page for managing events and classrooms reservation. For each event i save the day, the hour and the classroom where it will take place. I am currently working on a function to delete events and related reservations.

```
function deleteEvent(event_key, event_date, event_classroom_key) {
    if (event_classroom_key != null) {
        var ref_prenotation = firebase.database().ref().child('prenotation/'
        + event_date.getFullYear() + '/' 
        + (event_date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' 
        + event_date.getDate() + '/' 
        + event_classroom_key + '/');

        ref_prenotation.once('value', snap => {
            snap.forEach(childSnap => {
                childSnap.forEach(gcSnap => {
                    if (gcSnap.key == 'event_key') {
                        if (event_key == gcSnap.val()) {
                            ref_prenotation.child(childSnap.key).remove();
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }

    var event_ref = firebase.database().ref().child('event/');
    event_ref.child(event_key).remove();

    $('#event_details').hide();
    $('#main_events_page').show();
    loadEventList();
}
```

As you can see, to delete a reservation from the database i browse the database by year, month, day and classroom. In this way i get information about the individual hours booked for the classroom on the selected date.

Then i check whether the booked hours are referring to the event i want to delete and in case i delete them.
Then i delete the event record itself.

Each event and related reservations are generated as shown below.

```
$('#create_event_btn').on('click', () => {
    var today = Date.now() - (24*3600*1000);
    user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

    if (cs_selected_rows > 0 && ne_date >= today &&  eventTitle.value != "") {
        var event_prenotation = firebase.database().ref().child('event/').push({
            title : eventTitle.value,
            classroom : classroom_name,
            classroom_key : classroom_id,
            date : ne_date.getTime(),
            teacher : user.displayName,
            teacher_key : user.uid,
            starting_hour : selected_hours[0]
        });

        //create a reservation for the selected room, unless the event takes place abroad

        if (classroom_name != "Outdoor") {
            for (var i = 0; i < selected_hours.length; i++) {            
                firebase.database().ref().child('prenotation/'+year+'/'+month+'/'+day+'/'+classroom_id+'/'+selected_hours[i]+'/').set({
                event_key : event_prenotation.key,
                event : eventTitle.value,
                classroom : classroom_name
                });
            }
        }

        loadEventList();

        selected_hours = [];
        cs_selected_rows = 0;

        $('#new_event_page').hide();
        $('#main_events_page').show();
        $("#schedule_event_table_body").empty();

    } else if (ne_date < today) {
        alert('ERROR');
    }
});
```

The problem is that when I press the "delete" button related to an event, several events are removed, in addition to the one selected.
Something similar happens when I try to modify the data related to an event and often happens that the data of many other events are modified.
I noticed that this happens mainly when I access information about an event in the database through the site without changing anything. Then when I try to modify or delete another event, the first one is also affected.

I hope I have provided useful information about the problem. I do not use firebase for a long time but I think I'm doing something wrong in a systematic way because problems often happen to me.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a short representative snippet of your JSON (as text, no screenshots please)? You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I found a solution but the problem was absolutely not related to firebase. I simply linked a new listener to the same button every time switched to the informations of the different events. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Good to hear you found a solution. If you'd like to post it as an answer, maybe somebody can benefit from it in the future. Otherwise I'll vote to close the question as a "temporary problem".

Comment: Every time I was looking for information about an event I was attacking a listener to a button which eliminated (or changed) all the associated events and not just the requested one.